# scale out ssas tabular models

Tags: sql-server, ssas, dax

I did quite a few searches but could not find any answers. The question is: Is it possible to scale out tabular models developed in ssas? I believe that the answer is no as sass keeps data in memory due to xVelocity. Any feedback would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you vote for close, at least specify why!

Comment: The question is quite broad - what are the reasons for scaling? Are you having performance problems in general, load problems (too many requests), is there a particular query that can be optimized, etc? It would be helpful to get a specific question to a specific problem rather than "how do I scale tabular?".

Comment: I am just assessing the technology at the moment so sorry the question is too broad. My main concern is data storage - how does this work if the instances are distributed but a tabular model requires the data to be in local memory?